# BigQuery Find Arabic characters

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to find all of the rows that contain arabic characters?

I have a large data set of names and I would like to get all of the arabic names and treat the text file differently then the rest of my data set.

The only potential possibility that I have read is to upload a table containing all of the arabic characters and somehow do a JOIN/match. However I'd like to avoid this given my lack of knowledge of the arabic language.

Comment: In the meantime, my not so elegant solution is to regex for alphanumberic characters, but it's not really the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you will enjoy below and apply to whatever logic you have to implement

```
SELECT 
  v,
  IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(v, r'([\p{Cyrillic}]+)'), '') AS russian,
  IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(v, r'([\p{Arabic}]+)'), '') AS arabic,
  IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(v, r'([\p{Hebrew}]+)'), '') AS hebrew
FROM 
  (SELECT '12 - Table - Таблица' AS v),
  (SELECT '23 - Table - الطاولة' AS v),
  (SELECT '34 - Table - שולחן' AS v)
```

Result is

```
v                       russian     arabic      hebrew   
12 - Table - Таблица    Таблица          
23 - Table - الطاولة               الطاولة       
34 - Table - שולחן                              שולחן
```

Comment: Small nit (as native speaker of both Russian and Hebrew): The correct translation of "Таблица" to Hebrew is "טַבלָה". Word "שולחן" means "стол" :)

Comment: :o) I think when I put this example I meant to use Table as a стол. But somehow ended up with таблица - still this was cool quick excercise :o)